# Unable to set up name servers

Tags: dns, centos, cpanel, nameserver

I've set up a server at my house running cPanel and CentOS.
I'm unable to point a domain to the server using nameserver's.
I can how ever point it to my server using an A record.

I've set up port forwarding for ports: 80, 443, 2082 - 2096.

My server's host name is s1.example.com
Name server 1: ns1.s1.example.com
Name server 2: ns2.s1.example.com

example.com is hosted with a x10 premium it has no problems.
example.com is registered with crazy domains.

In the hosting I've made an A record's for s1.example.com, ns1.s1.example.com and ns2.s1.example.com witch all point to my IP.

With crazydomins I've created a glue record's for s1.example.com, ns1.s1.example.com and ns2.s1.example.com witch all point to my IP.

Using https://www.whatsmydns.net/, s1.example.com, ns1.s1.example.com and ns2.s1.example.com resolve perfectly.

How ever when I point example.net to my server using ns1.s1.example.com and ns2.s1.example.com, 24 hours later example.net isn't pointed to my server properly.

How do I correct this problem, so I can point domains to my server?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a NS for subdomain.

On ns resisted with domain registrar  add A records to you home IP

I use no-ip.org as my ip is on DHCP and have a cname to  EG. qwerty.no-ip.org so if the IP changes it sill works.

Comment: I don't have to worry about my IP changing. Should my nameservers be ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com instead of ns1.s1.example.com and ns2.s1.example.com?

Comment: Yes ns1.s1.example.com and ns2.s1.example.com and register the with your domain registrar  IE Godaddy or who ever you use.

Comment: Thanks, it all seems to be working fine. Domains are pointing to my server, but when I use the same network as the server is on s1.example.com (the server's hostname) doesn't resolve. But if I use a different internet connection it does. How can I fix this?

Comment: What to you see if you do nslookup or dig on names internal?   Is the public IP on the systems or is it nat?   can you access the system with public IP IE http//:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 or 443?

Comment: Visiting the Private IP and Local IP the page shows, on both 80 and 443. NSLOOKUP give me the following error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)", but nslookup to a domain pointing to my server return the correct ip.

Comment: example.com is hosted with x10 premium, s1.example.com is pointing to my IP via an A record. I also have a glue record with the domain registrar pointing to the server's IP.

Comment: If I set my computers DNS to Google's Public DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), the site resolves. But in the DHCP server settings, when I set it's DNS to Google's Public DNS, it doesn't work on different computer.